# PHP Button on each row of table

Tags: php, mysql, html

im making some application form in PHP.

im putting all info returned from the database into a table.

Now i want to create a button on each line that changes something in the DB of that line.

but i have no idea to do that :S

Thank you!

```
echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>Id</th>
<th>Name</th>
<th>Email</th>
<th>age</th>
<th>position</th>
<th>experience</th>
<th>motivation</th>
<th>date</th>
<th>status</th>
<th>test</th>
</tr>";

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
        echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['id'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['name'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['email'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['age'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['position'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['exp'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['motivation'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['date'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['status'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . '<input type="submit" name="submit" value="accept">' . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";

}
    echo "</table>";
```

EDIT: get it working using another script:

```
echo "<td><a href=\"edit.php?id=".$row['id']."&status=app\">Approve</a></td>";
```

and edit.php:

```
<?php
include("dbconnect.php");
$member_id = $_GET['id'];
$status = $_GET['status'];
echo $member_id;
echo $status;
if ($status == 'app')
    $query = "update apps set status = 'approved' where id = $member_id";
mysql_query($query) or die (mysql_error());  
?>
```

Comment: Which part are you having problems with? Putting the button on each line, or changing the database?

Comment: You might want to start by posting the code you've come up with so far.

Comment: I have no idea how to use the current row, i have created a button on each line

Comment: show us how far you got till now.

Comment: What the problem you are facing?

Comment: @Arpit Srivastava i don't know how to perform an action on the current row, as the table is dynamic

Comment: then you can use javascript or jquery for it...

Comment: @Arpit Srivastava i don't have any experience in both options, im also new to php

Comment: If you really want to do this in php only, i would suggest to create a form for each row and maybe $_POST the id of the row in a hidden field to identify the row in the database

Comment: Is it possible to use the OnClick function?

Comment: @puelo _create a form for each row_, its a dynamic table

Comment: check my app and have a look it's `jquery` and learn from it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create small form with parameters in the cell you want the button to do smth. This is the simpliest approach (approach with refresh).

One more solution is to use AJAX on button click and forward action to some endpoint. This way it would be dynamic and probably what you are want to implement.

Answer (score 1):

```
echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>Id</th>
<th>Name</th>
<th>Email</th>
<th>age</th>
<th>position</th>
<th>experience</th>
<th>motivation</th>
<th>date</th>
<th>status</th>
<th>test</th>
</tr>";

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
        echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['id'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['name'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['email'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['age'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['position'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['exp'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['motivation'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['date'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['status'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . '<form type="POST"><input type="hidden" name="whatever" value="$row['id']"><input type="submit" name="submit_btn" value="accept"></form>' . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";

}
    echo "</table>";
```

in this way, you could get a form in each row of the table. Now, you just need to use php POST function.

```
if(isset($_POST['submit_btn']))
{
//whatever u need to do
}
```